# How to activate MIDI controller in Ableton?

Tags: ableton

I have been having a problem in Ableton 8.2.2, when i turn on the Ableton and after that switch on my MIDI, Ableton never detect that. I have to restart Ableton and then it starts detecting the MIDI. So, how i can overcome with that?

My setup is : Core 2 duo, 4GB Ram, 1 TB HDD, ASUS 5KPLMN Motherboard and Windows 7.

Comment: Core 2 duo, 4GB RAM, 1 TB HARD DRIVE, ASUS 5KPLMN MOTHERBOARD

Comment: The OS version is Windows 7.

Comment: So, how can i solve this issue in my computer system?

Comment: If no user encountered the same experience, I would advice to directly ask your question to the [Ableton Live Forum](https://forum.ableton.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your help and i appreciate your advice. I will go through that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ableton Live 8, you can't plug and play MIDI devices, you have to connect them before lauching the software.

In Live 9 it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

As tomtomtom said Ableton Live 8 doesn't allow plug and play MIDI devices on Windows. This works on Mac.